# Does windows mobile broadcase a WM_CLOSE message?

Tags: windows-mobile, messaging

I've heard that Windows Mobile will broadcast a WM_CLOSE message to all inactive (?) windows if system memory falls below a certain threshold.  I think I'm seeing this occur with my app too.  But I cannot find any documentation to confirm this.  Anyone know about this?  Or know where I can find doc on it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

WM_HIBERNATE is the message that is sent to your app when system resources run low

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the platform may send WM_CLOSE to your application if memory pressure is high.  It will send a WM_HIBERNATE first, though.  [Here's some documentation on the process](http://blogs.msdn.com/wmshell/archive/2006/05/25/607263.aspx).